# Cargo registry directory

Tags: rust-cargo

How do I specify another directory where cargo keeps the unpacked sources, e.g. on Windows this is `%userprofile%/.cargo/registry/src`?

I working that is going to be a collection of crates like:

```
myproject-tree/
  foo
    +Cargo.toml
  bar
    +Cargo.toml
```

So I would like the dependencies to be loaded in unpacked somewhere near the `myproject-tree` directory, e.g.

```
myproject-tree/
cargo-cache/
```

I think that would make it easier to inspect the code of dependencies (e.g. in the code editors with file tree UI). I can see that there is CARGO_HOME that seems like it has something like this, but it does not look convenient, e.g. each time I am going to work with `myproject-tree` I have to set it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is possible. I think it called "vendoring" and repositories like Fuchsia and Mozilla has source copy of third-party crates in their repositories. This is what I have found:

- Cargo supports "[Source replacement](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/source-replacement.html)" thing configured in .cargo/config, which can be in a project relative dir:

> With this configuration Cargo attempts to look up all crates in the
>   directory "vendor" rather than querying the online registry at
>   crates.io. Using source replacement Cargo can express:
>
> Vendoring - custom sources can be defined which represent crates on
>   the local filesystem. These sources are subsets of the source that
>   they're replacing and can be checked into packages if necessary.
>
> Mirroring - sources can be replaced with an equivalent version which
>   acts as a cache for crates.io itself.

- There is a tool https://github.com/alexcrichton/cargo-vendor that can used to populate the directory with source codes of the dependencies:

> Simply run `cargo vendor` inside of any Cargo project: